# If $f$ is entire and $|f|\geq 1$, then show $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I know I'm going to use Liouville's Theorem, but my main question is why is $1/|f(z)|$ entire as well if $f$ is entire? Is this just a basic property: if $f$ is entire, then $1/f$ is entire? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Careful: even if $f$ is entire, $|f|$ and $1/|f|$ need not be.  However, if $f$ never vanishes, then $1/f$ is entire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ and $f(z_0)$ is nonzero, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, and from here you can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$.  Then, since $|f(z)| \geq 1$ for all $z$ and is entire, therefore so is $g$ and moreover, we have that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z$.

Hence by Liouville's theorem, $g$ is bounded, but then so is $f$.

Comment: If $|f(z)| \geq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $f$ has no zeros.

Comment: An alternate solution is to use Picard's Theorem, that is, if $f$ is entire and omits at least two points in the complex plane, then $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general. You must use the fact that f has no zeroes...