# Complex analytic functions $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $|f|>1$ are constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been struggling with this problem:

Suppose $f \colon \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is analytic on $ \mathbb C$ and that $|f(z)| > 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. Show that $f$ must be constant on $ \mathbb C$.

The suggestion given is "What can you say about $1/f$?"

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by answering the question in the given suggestion. What can you say about $1/f$?

Comment: f must be analytic, so f cannot equal 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $f$ is entire and $|f|\geq 1$, then show $f$ is constant.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576724/if-f-is-entire-and-f-geq-1-then-show-f-is-constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\left|f(z)\right|>1, \, f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Thus you can define the function $g(z)=1/f(z)$. Consequently $g(z)$ is an entire function-$f(z)$ is entire-and is bounded because $\frac{1}{\left|f(z)\right|}<1$. Hence by Liouville's theorem $g$ must be constant, which yields that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $1/f$ is entire (since $f$ is never $0$) and bounded.  By Liouville's Theorem, it is constant.

Comment: How can I show that 1/f is entire? And the theorem says that f must be entire, not 1/f

Comment: @Alfred $\frac{1}{f}$ is entire because its a composition of two entire functions: the constant function $1$ and the given $f(z)$. Like peter mentioned, if you define $g(z) = 1/f(z)$ then things become a little more clearer.